# Fill in the blanks excel formula to replace particular text in a cell

Tags: excel, formula

I'm looking for a formula to find and replace particular piece of text in a cell.
It sound a bit confusing but you can see what I mean by viewing the following image.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is when I fill for example cell B1 I would like to replace "**SYS-NAME**" in cell A25 and other cells where "**SYS-NSME**" is present.

Comment: Would a macro be allowed too? Just the click of a button and poof, your config is ready :) Will the first part always be a fixed ranged like that or could it expand/decrease?

Comment: Macro is allowed I can't see why not. I assume by first part you mean cells from A1 to A20, yes this will be fixed.

Comment: Ok, so A1 to A20 is a fixed range?

Comment: that's correct this will stay as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `**` before and after your values. You could change it to `""` instead if you want to highlight those inserted values. `**` will cause the entire cell to be replaced, instead of its match.

So the code splits column A into 2 sub columns. The first column runs until the first blank row, this contains all your variables and their new value. The second column runs until the end of the last used row. This contains your configuration with the variables that need to be changed.

```
Sub FindReplace()
    Dim NewText, OldText As String
    Dim LastRowText, i As Integer

    LastRowText = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 1

    Do While i < LastRowText
        OldText = Range("A" & i).Value
        NewText = Range("B" & i).Value
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRowText & ":A" & LastRow)
            .Replace OldText, NewText, xlPart
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Option without a macro**

In your configuration, edit each line with a variable to the following format. This will instantly update the configuration file too.

```
Cell A25: ="sysname " & B1
Cell A34: ="irf domain " & B2
...
```

Comment: This kind of works but even after replacing ** with "" the whole cell is being replaced. Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: @p3dr0, that's odd .. Could you send me a screenshot of your Excel with ** changed to ""? This is my example and this is the result: http://i67.tinypic.com/wrgqpi.png

Comment: It clearly works in your example. Here is my screenshot http://imgur.com/YldFUYv not sure what might be causing this. If I get rid of "" all together will tat make any difference?

Comment: @p3dr0, what is your column B defined as? Could you set it all to text or general? Or could you send me your file?

Comment: yup it was me using it on the wrong file.... Thank you very much for your help that works just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"**SYS-NAME**","MYSYSNAME")
```

starting in B1.

Comment: Thanks Tom, unfortunately that didn't work. After pasting your formula all I can see is sysname in B2.[link](http://i65.tinypic.com/2lxvyc3.png)

Comment: You should be able to see "MYSYSNAME" if you make the column wider, but I think I might have misunderstood your requirements.